# Under what circumstances does EXCEPTION_RECORD link to another nested exception?

Tags: c++, exception, structured-exception, nested-exceptions

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinNT/ns-winnt-_exception_record) for `_EXCEPTION_RECORD` says about one of it's members, `struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD *ExceptionRecord`

> A pointer to an associated EXCEPTION_RECORD structure. Exception records can be chained together to provide additional information when nested exceptions occur.

However, I haven't been able to provoke such a situation of nested structured exceptions. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void Handle0(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS pex) {
    std::cout << "chain0 = " << pex->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionRecord << std::endl;
}

void Handle1(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS pex) {
    std::cout << "chain1 = " << pex->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionRecord << std::endl;
    __try {
        throw 3;
    } __except( Handle0(GetExceptionInformation()), EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER ) {}
}

int main() {
    __try {
        throw 3;
    } __except( Handle1(GetExceptionInformation()), EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER ) {}
    return 0;
}
```

The `pex->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionRecord` is always `nullptr`. Under what circumstances do I get a link to a nested `_EXCEPTION_RECORD` there?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/differences-in-exception-handling-behavior-under-clr?view=vs-2019):

> When an exception is raised during the processing of an exception
> filter within ... native code ... a nested exception is raised, the
> `ExceptionRecord` field in the `EXCEPTION_RECORD` structure (as returned
> by `GetExceptionInformation`) is set, and the `ExceptionFlags` field sets
> the `0x10` bit. The following example illustrates this difference in
> behavior:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#ifndef false
#define false 0
#endif

int *p;

int filter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionPointers) {
   PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord =
                     ExceptionPointers->ExceptionRecord;

   if ((ExceptionRecord->ExceptionFlags & 0x10) == 0) {
      // not a nested exception, throw one
      *p = 0; // throw another AV
   }
   else {
      printf("Caught a nested exception\n");
      return 1;
    }

   assert(false);

   return 0;
}

void f(void) {
   __try {
      *p = 0;   // throw an AV
   }
   __except(filter(GetExceptionInformation())) {
      printf_s("We should execute this handler if "
                 "compiled to native\n");
    }
}

int main() {
   __try {
      f();
   }
   __except(1) {
      printf_s("The handler in main caught the "
               "exception\n");
    }
}
```

I believe it is also set if you try to continue non-continuable exception. In this case `EXCEPTION_RECORD` will represent `EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE_EXCEPTION`, while its `ExceptionRecord` will point to original exception.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I tried it in VC2019 v16.11(just `cl your.cpp`, no extra compiler option needed). I see that "Caught a nested exception\n" is printed; but, at that point, `ExceptionRecord->ExceptionRecord` is still **NULL**. So the OP's question is not answered yet.